# Package installation time is getting *drastically* vary, how to optimize it?

Tags: salesforcedx, performance, unlocked-package, cicd

We have unlocked packages with CICD enabled. Sometime those package installation **takes 5 mins and sometime goes till 30+ mins**. Since I know it had been installed in 5 mins, why its getting weird installation time?

I checked the pipeline(Gitlab) with logs, I found that **it's taking time for installing only(`sfdx force:package:install` command only)**. Other stuff is working faster. Since, it's installing with Salesforce resource(network) not the machine on which CICD script is getting executed, how I can make it steady and less?

Any ideas to optimize and make it steady will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A given installation may only take a short amount of time, but you also need to keep in mind that a deployment/installation requires "exclusive" access to certain tables, which are made read-only during that time. This is to guarantee atomicity (i.e. an installation can only fully succeed or fail).

If you request to install five packages, then four of the packages will be stalled until the first completes. Similarly, if an administrator decides to create a sharing rule that results in a significant recalculation time (I've seen it take *days* in some cases), then you'll be blocked from other administrative changes, such as installations, until it completes.

In the example above, if you have six installation requests queued that take five minutes each, that would explain why an individual package appears to take 30 minutes to install, even though the package itself only takes a few minutes.

When using CI/CD, it is entirely possible for several developers to quickly release several packages close to each other, so it means that someone will have to wait while the earlier requests are processed.

While it is also true that server load plays a part in installation time (see other answer), the *main* limitation usually comes from the one-package-at-a-time system described above. To minimize this effect, make sure your unlocked packages are reasonably small and that developers aren't constantly installing micro-patches. Some discipline is required to make CI/CD useful.

Comment: We handle the CI part of this scenario by ensuring that each CI execution targets a brand new, dedicated scratch org. Fortunately we don't have to do CD :)

Comment: Agree with you and Phil's answer. Regarding streamlining we only have 2 approvers, so that part is handled. Regarding length also, we broker application in 3 pckgs. So I got question on smallest only. Now only relying on Salesforce part. :(

Answer (score 4):

It is all down to the fact Salesforce provides a [multi-tenanted solution](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/multi_tenant_architecture). Multiple orgs exist on the same virtual and physical servers. If there's heavy load on the server (across all the orgs that it supports) then Salesforce starts throttling processing performed in specific orgs, prioritizing user interactions and reducing capacity for async processing (of which package installation is an example - if you ever installed a large package you will see that the UI waits a certain amount of time then tells you that you'll be notified by email which demonstrates it is handled internally as async).

There's no way to control this and you'll have to simply live with it.

Comment: ohkk even though with performance edition, it won't give preference? :(

Comment: Yes I agree with big packages, but we have one small pckg(others are kind-of big) as well with 3 objs n 5 components, i was expecting this to go steady at least.

Comment: Even then you are just one of many users with orgs on a given server. Clearly different editions and types of org will have different prioritization when resources become scarce - you may have noticed that scratch orgs frequently perform quite poorly, for example.

Comment: The point is, you have no idea what else is happening on the server for your org. If there's lots of user activities on other orgs on the same server, your org's async processing will suffer. It's that simple.

Comment: Thank you for focusing light on the server side. Yeah that scratch org I experienced in pipeline.

Comment: @PhilW is any way to check the status of the specific server which hosts my scratch orgs?

Comment: @hsd Yes. You need to find the "instance" name for your scratch orgs (if you have access to one check the Company Information tab in Setup on that scratch org) then go to https://status.salesforce.com and search for that instance. You'll see the status for the instance there.